# Google Map ToolBar not getting displayed when markers are added dynamically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implement `Map ToolBar` on `google maps`. I have done the following coding but the `toolbar` is not getting displayed.I refered this [link](http://www.tech.theplayhub.com/map_toolbar_issue_in_map_v2_android/). Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. My code is a s follows:

```
 if (isGooglePlayServicesIsInstalled(getActivity())) {
   googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
   MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng(15.4989, 15.4989)).title("title");
   googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
   googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
   }


   @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    }
```

Google play gradle:`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`

Comment: you have to add tools manually whatever you need like this
1.googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnable(true);
 2.googleMap.getUiSettings().<your tool whatever you want>;

Comment: I ahve added it  as `googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);`

Comment: that i know you already shown in question, what about my code did you added ???

Comment: still doesn't work..i addedd as  ` googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);` It showed a round compass only once.Then it is not getting dispalyed again.

Comment: can u post whole code with activity, xml, manifest

Comment: @Nitin I have added some more codes pls check

Comment: The toolbar doesnt show unless you click a map marker. I enable the map UI toolbar do this when the map object is created

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell it seems that you forget to `return false` to let default action works. Check out the [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker_click_events).

Here's what I do:

```
// add marker dynamically
lastScooterLocation = new LatLng(lastScooterLat, lastScooterLng);
lastScooterMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_map_pin_normal))
            .anchor(0.0f, 0.0f)
            .position(lastScooterLocation)
            .draggable(false)
            .title(getString(R.string.strings_last_scooter_location)));

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            showBottomViewOf(BottomViewState.HIDE_ALL);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            // return true will prevent any further map action from happening
            return false;

        }
    });
```